# Mapreduce in MPI

Tags: mapreduce, mpi, word-count

I want to use word count on this dataset :

http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Movies.html

I can't find a program on the internet which will help me to do so.

Please suggest something ?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is pretty amenable to MapReduce.  If you're a python guy, you might like mrjob, which actually uses a word count example in a lot of their documentation:
http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/writing-mrjobs.html

Comment: It should be a pretty tractable problem with MPI.  But it's going to be more difficult as you'll have to deal with all the communication by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [easyLambda](https://github.com/haptork/easylambda). It is a C++ and MPI library based on data-flow and map-reduce. It has a word-count example as well.